# Are blocks passed as arguments?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I can pass arguments to functions like this:

```
func 1, 2, 3
```

or I can use brackets like:

```
func(1, 2, 3)
```

Later on I learned about functions like `list.each` which I pass (not sure if this is what's really happening) a block to operate on each element:

```
list.each {|x| puts x}
```

I assumed this just passed the block as an argument to the `each` function, but this doesn't seem to be the case because:

```
list.each( {|x| puts x} )
```

does not work.

I realized this when shown:

```
5.upto(9) {|x| puts x}
```

Which doesn't make sense at all if the block is simply an argument.

What's going on here? Any resource you can point me to to help explain this, and perhaps other structure things that aren't immediately obvious?

Comment: You may find this a helpful starting point: [http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)

Comment: This is a special syntax created specifically for passing a block to a function. For each function invocation, you may pass one block outside the regular arguments list. The block is still appended to the argument list within the context of the called function.

Comment: @Matt - Since you are learning Ruby have a look at: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/ruby - Really good resource for anyone wanting to learn the core fundamentals of the ruby language

Comment: @David, that's where I am! :)

Comment: @Matt pro keep at it!

Comment: Ah grasshopper, this is a good question to ask. :-) Ruby is an awesome language, and blocks are a very powerful part of it. You'll find they are the key to much of what occurs in the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blocks are indeed a bit special, but can also be used as arguments. Consider this function:

```
def greet
  yield "Hello"
end

greet{ |greeting| puts "#{greeting} to you" }
```

You could also write the exact same thing like this:

```
def greet(&block)
  block.call("Hello")
end

greet{ |greeting| puts "#{greeting} to you" }

# which is equivalent to:
my_proc = proc{ |greeting| puts "#{greeting}, nice to see you." }
greet(&my_proc)
```

In the end, blocks are a special form of procs with a special syntax which makes them more usable. But you can still access the procs and pass them around.

Comment: +1. I'd add that there are a few gotchas. Blocks are technically Proc objects, which are similar to but not exactly identical to lambda objects. Their respective behaviors with e.g. splat arguments aren't entirely identical, for instance. (Admittedly related to Ruby bugs, which might have been fixed since I last did any serious amounts of work using Ruby, but there were vivid subtleties such as this back then.) Also, note that by using the `&block` syntax, you *explicitly* create a Proc object at each call -- even if no block was passed, leading to slower code due to excess object creation.

Answer (score 4):

methods can accept exactly one block, sort of as a special argument.

```
def foo
  yield 123
end

foo { |x| puts x }
#=> 123
```

Note how that method accepts zero arguments, but still accepts a block.  That's because this syntax of hanging a block off a method is sort of a special case.  Any block passed to a method can be run with the `yield` keyword.  And you can even ask if a block was passed in with the `block_given?` keyword.

If you want to capture it in a local variable, you can do that with some special syntax.

```
def foo(a, &block)
  block.call a
end

foo(123) { |x| puts x }
#=> 123
```

In this case, you are capturing the block argument explicitly, with that `&` prefix in the argument list.  You now have a variable for that block, which you can send the `call` message in order to execute.  Just know this must appear at the end of the argument list.

Also note the parens. `foo(123) { |x| puts x }`. The argument list stops, the parens close and the attached block comes after.  Again, because this is a special case in the syntax.

Comment: thank you.

Can you call something like: `def two_func_in(&func1, &func2)` ? What would that call look like? EDIT: You said "methods can accept exactly one block". Is that the answer to this question?

Comment: `def two_func_in(&func1, &func2)` is not valid ruby.  You can only _attach_ one block to a method.  But there are other ways to pass in some code as a basic simple argument. Like [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html) objects, for one, though the syntax for dealing with that is different.